# Raspberry Pi I²C configuration

Tags: python, i2c, raspberry-pi4, pwm

I have some troubles connecting my PCA9685 to my Raspberry Pi 4b.
I have enabled second I²C port to enable connection with the PCA9685 chip. When I type `i2cdetect -y 2` to my terminal it detects the address as 0x40. However, when I run my code it states that no I²C device found at address 0x40.

I tried to reconnect PCA9685 to default I²C bus of my Raspberry Pi. It worked while using my default bus. I don't know why it doesn't work on my I²C bus #2. The code I was trying to implement was:

```py
import time
import board
import busio
from adafruit_pca9685 import PCA9685
from adafruit_motor import servo

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
pca = PCA9685(i2c, address=0x40)
pca.frequency = 50

servo_motor = servo.Servo(pca.channels[0])

while True:
   servo_motor.angle = 0
   time.sleep(1)
   servo_motor.angle = 90
   time.sleep(1)
   servo_motor.angle = 180
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: So, what is the problem with using in-kernel driver (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/pwm/pwm-pca9685.c) for that PWM chip?

Comment: seems a bit pi specific, try here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/